# Is "whomever who did this" correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

I'd like to thank whomever who have role to make this event possible..

is "whomever who" is correct here? if not how else could it be formed?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Whom" (and its related prepositions) is frequently misused -- even more so because, in modern English, it is unnecessary.  "Who" is acceptable in any context.  However, if you must use "whom", remember that "who" is for the *subject* of a sentence, and *whom* is for the object.

> *Who* made this event possible?
>
> *Whom* does this event honor?

[Some more information on who and whom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147747/to-whoever-it-may-concern)

In your example, you are referring to the person *who* made the event possible.  So you should use "whoever" and not "whomever":

> I would like to thank *whoever* made this event possible.

This may be confusing, since you might think that "who" is the object of "thank". Actually "who" is the *subject* of the clause "who made this event possible". [More information on who vs. whom in subordinate clauses](http://www.esf.edu/writingprogram/tipsheets/whom.htm).

I would have thought that both "whoever who" and "whomever who" are never correct, but apparently [people do use these.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=whoever+who%2C+whomever+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).  I don't know where or how, since they seem incorrect to me.  Instead (again, if you must) you could use "whosoever" or "whomsoever" in place of "whoever" and "whomever":

> *Whosoever* wants to go to the event, let me know as soon as possible.
>
> Invite *whomsoever* you like to the event.

Comment: if whoever belongs to "made this event possible", where is the object of "thank"? how could only 1 whoever be enough to fulfill 2 roles both subject and object?

Comment: @CeyhunÖzsoylu Yeah I know.  It's confusing to me too.  Please see the article I linked to about who and whom in subordinate clauses.  Apparently the rule is to use the function of "who" within the clause over its function in the main sentence.  Of course this is yet another reason why I never use "whom".

Comment: @CeyhunÖzsoylu possibly, another way to look at it is that the *entire subordinate clause* is the object of "thank".

Answer (score 3):

Most people don't use "whom" (or "whomever") at all. But among people who do so, this isn't right, for two reasons.

First, "who(m)ever" is a version of "who(m)", so it's very odd repeating the "who".

Secondly, "whom(ever)" is only used when it is *not* the subject *of its clause*. Here, it is a "fused relative" (equivalent to something like "the people - whoever they are - who") and is the subject in the relative clause "who(ever) made this possible" (replacing your "have role to make" which I don't quite understand the meaning of).

You could use "whomever" where it is not the subject of its clause:

> Say to whomever you see, that I am here.

but

> Say to whoever comes that I am here.

But, as I say, not many people would use "whomever" at all.